# which type can use to store abi in a contract

Tags: contract-development

If I want to store abi in contract, which type can be use? and How can I get it later.

For example, if I use `bytes` to store a contract's abi. How can I use `JSON.parse` to get it. I have not find a  proper api in web3.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you would want to store an ABI in a contract. ABI is for interacting with a contract from a node and it's not needed inside the blockchain. Furthermore, storing it in `bytes` would cost you a lot of gas.

Comment: Suggestion: verify the contract on Etherscan, and it will store its ABI for you.

Comment: It seems to me that `string` would be most appropriate.